# Wi-Fi disconnects when USB ethernet connects

Tags: wireless, usb, ethernet

As per the title wifi drops connection whenever usb ethernet connects. My ethernet connection provides internet and the wifi access to LAN. This was working for the last year but suddenly stopped.

Here is the output for the following commands:

```
$ nmcli device 
DEVICE             TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION         
enxc84bd6b25f34    ethernet  connected     Wired connection 1 
wlp0s20f3          wifi      connected     TeamX              
p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3  wifi-p2p  disconnected  --                 
enp0s31f6          ethernet  unavailable   --                 
lo                 loopback  unmanaged     --    

$ ip route
default via 192.168.10.254 dev enxc84bd6b25f34 proto dhcp metric 100 
default via 192.168.10.1 dev wlp0s20f3 proto static metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp0s20f3 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.10.0/24 dev enxc84bd6b25f34 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.49 metric 100 
192.168.10.0/24 dev wlp0s20f3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.70 metric 600 

$ ifconfig
enp0s31f6: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 98:fa:9b:c7:8e:8a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xea200000-ea220000  

enxc84bd6b25f34: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.10.49  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.10.255
        inet6 fe80::83ed:489a:d913:a39b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether c8:4b:d6:b2:5f:34  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2134636  bytes 154615983 (154.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4394247  bytes 6207313755 (6.2 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 11709  bytes 1420993 (1.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 11709  bytes 1420993 (1.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp0s20f3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.10.70  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.10.255
        inet6 fe80::6ed:33ff:fe3e:beb7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 04:ed:33:3e:be:b7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 154  bytes 15241 (15.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 611  bytes 142753 (142.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your wifi and ethernet are on the same subnet.
The wifi isn't actually dropped, it is deprioritized.

You have two routes to 192.168.10.0/24 and two default routes.

You might be able to fix this by adjusting priority on the two routes.

If these are actually separate networks, you should instead change the subnet address of one of them so they are different.  (I.e., 192.168.1.x)   (If you do this, you have to change it for every device on that network, not just your computer.)

Comment: Yes these are two separate networks. How can I adjust priorities?
wlp0s20f3 connection is connected to my access point. Gateway ip is 192.168.10.1
Should I change that?

Comment: If they are separate, it would be better to renumber one of them.

Comment: The consequence of not renumbering them is that you won't be able to access computers in one of the two networks, even if you have priorities set.

Comment: Thanks will change it